# Audiobook about 19th century New York immigrant obsessed with photography and a red-headed woman

Tags: identification-request

Back in the early 1990's my father got an audiobook from the library about a German or European immigrant in 19th century New York (I think it mentioned the main male protagonist seeing the Statue of Liberty).

The main character is obsessed with photography, his new camera, and this red headed woman. I remember a scene where he is in bed with the red head, and the father comes bursting in. I believe the father breaks the German immigrant's camera, which leads the German into a fit of rage. Or something like that happens.

I asked my dad years later what the novel or story was called, but he couldn't remember, and he's passed away since 2010, so there's no way of asking him.

Comment: Also posted to https://www.nypl.org/blog/2017/11/22/finding-book-forgotten-title?page=5

Comment: There, Alice Hoffman's [*The Museum of Extraordinary Things*](https://www.kirkusreviews.com/book-reviews/alice-hoffman/museum-of-extraordinary-things/) was suggested, but it looks like a poor match to me since while it's set in New York and involves a photographer, the main character is the webhanded young woman, Coralie and the photographer is Jewish.

Comment: @SeanDuggan does the photographer's being jewish preclude them from being german?

Comment: @Spagirl: You have a point. His name of "Eddie Cohen" is a bit closer to "not German", but what do I know?

Comment: Plot summary at https://www.supersummary.com/the-museum-of-extraordinary-things/summary/ also doesn't seem right.

Comment: May this have been 'Amerika' by Franz Kafka? IIRC, in the opening paragraphs of the novel the protagonist sights the Statue of Liberty, and later on they have interactions with at least 3 women, one of them being Brunelda, who, having gone back to read that particular section, is described as wearing a red dress, so perhaps you misremembered a description of her dress as a description of her hair? I don't however recall them being interested in photography at all.